# Quiero eliminar un elemento de una tabla en sequelize, pero dicha tabla tiene una relacion muchos a muchos

Tags: nodejs, postgresql, express, sequelize.js

Estoy intentando eliminar un elemento de una tabla con relación muchos a muchos, usando postgres y sequelize, pero no me deja eliminarlo directamente, me dice que viola la llave foránea de otra tabla. imagino que si la elimino quedaría un hueco en la tabla intermedia, que opción podría utilizar para eliminarlo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola Eduardo bienvenido, la pregunta debe ser autocontenida, esto es que no dependa de imágenes o enlaces, por favor, edita tu pregunta elimina las imágenes, y agrega tu código y el mensaje de error como texto, gracias..

Comment: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822 Lectura sugerida. Saludos :D

Answer (score 0):

logre resolver el problema, en primera instancia tenía que eliminar todas relaciones que coincidan con el id, en la tabla intermedia, para luego poder eliminar de la tabla principal.